# Blocking call on MoveIts CurrentStateMonitor?

Tags: ros2, moveit, ros-humble, multithreading

I've created my own `move_group_interface` due to some complications with the [original](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/humble/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/src/move_group_interface.cpp) and the need to expose more functionality of `move_group` to my application. Within the Gazebo simulation it is working as intended, unfortunately it doesn't work on the real robot yet. I receive the error:

```
[motion_interface-14] [INFO][1708423092.297431201] [moveit_ros.current_state_monitor]: Didn't receive robot state (joint angles) with recent timestamp within 1.000000 seconds. Requested time 1708423091.297018, but last received state has time 1708423091.294824.
```

This is when I request the current robot state for the planning request to `move_group` the function `bool CurrentStateMonitor::waitForCurrentState(const rclcpp::Time& t, double wait_time_s) const` is called. When running without using simulation time, it will wait for a new message on `/joint_states` topic until the wait time is reached. It should be notified by `void CurrentStateMonitor::jointStateCallback(const sensor_msgs::msg::JointState::ConstSharedPtr& joint_state)`. This function will get called until I request the current robot state, then it will be only called after the first function finished. For me it seems to be some kind of parallel execution issue, so I've tried calling `waitForCurrentState` by:

```
std::future<bool> hasCurrentState = std::async(&planning_scene_monitor::CurrentStateMonitor::waitForCurrentState,
                                               this->options_.current_state_monitor,
                                               this->node_ptr->get_clocke()->now(),
                                               wait_seconds);
```

Sadly this hasn't yielded any positive result. Since the subscription to `joint_states` is convoluted and buried in `CurrentStateMonitorMiddlewareHandle` I have not really a good overview on what is happening. I presume some kind of need for multi-threaded executors or/and callback groups. I'm however hesitant to do changes in these parts of `MoveIt`. I've tried out to give the subscription a reentrant callback group, but also without positive result.

Maybe you can bring me on track of what is going on.